# Facing Issue on Creating MVVM Pattern From An ESRI Runtime 100.2 Existing App

Tags: .net, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net, model-view-viewmodel

Following [This Sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/latest/wpf/guide/develop-your-first-map-app.htm) I am hoping to be able a real MVVM pattern from the tutorial but based on my understanding the application is missing the `Model` and `View` classes!

I have the `MapViewModel.cs` like this

```
 public class MapViewModel
    {
        public MapViewModel(){ }

        private Map _map = new Map(Basemap.CreateStreets());
        public Map Map
        {
            get { return _map; }
            set { _map = value;  }
        }

    }
```

and the `MainWindow.xaml`

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MapViewModel x:Key="MapViewModel" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <esri:MapView Map="{Binding Map, Source={StaticResource MapViewModel}}" />
</Grid>
```

but whre are the `"MapView` and `"MapModel` classes? Can you please help me to extracts and create those classes from the `MapViewModel` and create a real MVVM model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, your Xaml behaves as a `View` tier which contains the `MapView`. You can think that the `MapView` is the `view` for the `Map` which is the `Model` and you use `MapViewModel` to clue them together.

Remember to implement property changed to your view model as well so later if you change the Map-model, the change gets propagated to the MapView-view.

Hopefully, that wasn't too confusing :)